# asm usage of memory location operands

Tags: memory, assembly, x86, yasm

I am in trouble with the definition 'memory location'. According to the 'Intel 64 and IA-32 Software Developer's Manual' many instruction can use a memory location as operand.
For example MOVBE (move data after swapping bytes):
Instruction: MOVBE **m32**, r32

The question is now how a memory location is defined;
I tried to use variables defined in the .bss section:

```
section .bss
    memory: resb 4          ;reserve 4 byte
    memorylen: equ $-memory

section .text
global _start

_start:
    MOV R9D, 0x6162630A
    MOV [memory], R9D
    SHR [memory], 1
    MOVBE [memory], R9D
```

EDIT:->

```
    MOV EAX, 0x01
    MOV EBX, 0x00
    int 0x80
```

<-EDIT
If SHR is commented out yasm (yasm -f elf64 .asm) compiles without problems but when executing stdio shows: **Illegal Instruction** 
And if MOVBE is commented out the following error occurs when compiling: **error: invalid size for operand 1**

How do I have to allocate memory for using the 'm' option shown by the instruction set reference?
[CPU=x64, Compiler=yasm]

Comment: @CraigAnderson the low 32 bits of `R9`.

Comment: Thanks @Jester.  FYI to everyone else - I asked what R9D was but then deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is all your code, you are falling off at the end into uninitialized region, so you will get a fault. That has nothing to do with allocating memory, which you did right. You need to add code to terminate your program using an exit system call, or at least put an endless loop so you avoid the fault (kill your program using `ctrl+c` or equivalent).

Update: While the above is true, the `illegal instruction` here is more likely caused by the fact that your cpu simply does not support the `MOVBE` instruction, because not all do. If you look in the reference, you can see it says `#UD If CPUID.01H:ECX.MOVBE[bit 22] = 0.` That is trying to tell you that a particular flag bit in the `ECX` register returned by the `01` leaf of the `CPUID` instruction shows support of this instruction. If you are on linux, you can conveniently check in `/proc/cpuinfo` whether you have the `movbe` flag or not.

As for the invalid operand size: you should generally specify the operand size when it can not be deduced from the instruction. That said, `SHR` accepts all sizes (byte, word, dword, qword) so you should really not get that error at all, but you might get an operation of unexpected default size. You should use `SHR dword [memory], 1` in this case, and that also makes `yasm` happy.

Oh, and +1 for reading the intel manual ;)

Comment: I forgot to copy the return part but it exists in the code compiled  - sorry for that. I'll update the code above immediately.
Specifying the the size does the trick for SHR. Thank you for your help!
Do you also know why MOVBE shows up an Illegal Instruction?

Comment: Wow - Thank you for this quick help. This forum is incredible.
As you described there is no >movbe< flag.